# Referencing last used row in a data frame

Tags: r

I couldn't find the answer in any previously asked questions, but I believe this is an easy one.

I have the below two lines of code, which take in data from excel in a specific range (using readxl for this).  The range itself only goes through row 2589 in the excel document, but it will update dynamically (it's a time series) and to ensure I capture the different observations (rows) as they're added, I've included rows to 10000 in the read_excel range argument.

In the end, I'd like to run charts on this data, but a key part of this is identifying the last used row, without manually updating the code row for the latest date.  I've tried using nrow but to no avail.

```
Raw_Index_History <- read_excel("RData.xlsx", range = "ReturnsA6:P10000",     col_names = TRUE)
Raw_Index_History <- Raw_Index_History[nrow(Raw_Index_History),]
```

Does anybody have any thoughts or advice?  Thanks very much.

Comment: If its a time series....why not use time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to answer your question if you include an example.
Not knowing how your data looks like answers are likely going to be a bit vague.

Does your data contain NAs? If not it should be straight forward to remove the empty rows with

> na.omit(Raw_Index_History)

It appears you also have control over the excel spreadsheet. So in case your data does contain NAs you could have some default value in your empty rows that will get overwritten as soon as a new data point is recorded. This will allow you to filter your dataframe accordingly.

> Raw_Index_History[!grepl("place_holder", Raw_Index_History$column_with_placeholder),]

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate your help.  I'm going with na.omit, didn't realize that would work in this situation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect data in the spreadsheet to grow, you can specify only the columns to include, instead of a defined boundary.

Something like this ...

```
Raw_Index_History <- read_excel("RData.xlsx", 
                                sheet = 1,
                                range = cell_cols("A:P"),  # Only cols, no rows
                                col_names = TRUE)
```

Every time you run the code, R will pull in the data from columns between `A:P` up until the last populated row.

This will be a more elegant approach to your use case. (Consider what you'd do when your data crosses 10000 rows in the future)

Comment: Thank you so much!  Can you tell me how/if I can give you or others a +1 on this forum?

Comment: You're welcome. You can [Vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer using the upward and downward triangles on the left side of a post. Also, if you find an answer satisfactory, you can mark your question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the post can be closed. Otherwise it will remain open.